# get the count of the field from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of json response .which I want to make it in report format.
I have data for may,jun,july based work week wise 'week1,week2,week3,week4'. I want to count the weekly total  for specific month.I want to create it as table.I want to get the count for username name based for specific meetingHash.

expected json response as

```
["may":[{"week":"Week1","MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized","count":2,"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju"},
        {"week":"Week2","MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting","count":1,"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju"},
        {"week":"Week1","MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized","count":2,"UserName":"Priya"},
        {"week":"Week2","MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting","count":1,"UserName":"Priya"}
],
 "Jun":[{"week":"Week2","MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting","count":1,"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju"},
          {"week":"Week1","MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings","count":1,"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju"},
          {"week":"Week2","MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting","count":1,"UserName":"Priya"},
          {"week":"Week1","MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings","count":1,"UserName":"Priya"}
],"Jul":[{"week":"Week3","MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings","count":1,"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju"},
         {"week":"Week1","MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings","count":1,"UserName":"Priya"}]]
```

```js
const response=[
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "monthinwords": "Jun"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "Jun"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
    "Subject": "Test Automation",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
    "week": "Week 3",
    "monthinwords": "July"
  },
  
  
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "monthinwords": "Jun"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "Jun"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "monthinwords": "May"
  },
  {
    "UserName": "Priya",
    "Subject": "Test Automation",
    "Geo": "Europe",
    "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "monthinwords": "July"
  },
];
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const result = response.reduce((r, entry) => {
  const { monthinwords } = entry;

  r[monthinwords] = [...r[monthinwords] || [], { ...entry }];

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

This will return the items grouped by `monthinwords`:

```js
{ May: [
    { UserName: 'Sarathy Devaraju',
      Subject: 'Multi-layered Testing Discussion',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: 'Hold/Uncategorized',
      week: 'Week 1',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    },
    { UserName: 'Sarathy Devaraju',
      Subject: 'Multi-layered Testing Discussion',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: 'Hold/Uncategorized',
      week: 'Week 1',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    },
    { UserName: 'Sarathy Devaraju',
      Subject: 'Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: '1st Presentation / Meeting',
      week: 'Week 2',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    },
    { UserName: 'Priya',
      Subject: 'Multi-layered Testing Discussion',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: 'Hold/Uncategorized',
      week: 'Week 1',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    },
    { UserName: 'Priya',
      Subject: 'Multi-layered Testing Discussion',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: 'Hold/Uncategorized',
      week: 'Week 1',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    },
    { UserName: 'Priya',
      Subject: 'Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International',
      Geo: 'Europe',
      MeetingHash: '1st Presentation / Meeting',
      week: 'Week 2',
      monthinwords: 'May'
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: may I know how to debug inside response.reduce((r, entry) => {}

Comment: I want to get the count of meetingHash for specific user

Comment: I am sorry, what do you wish to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the count based on month and weeks

Comment: The count of what?